# jquery show selected drop down value

Tags: jquery

Left part is the drop down to choose different music. Show the music name in the right part. The code can only show the first one. When I select another music, it cannot change to the current value.

html:

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Music</label>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select class="form-control" name="music" id="selectedmusic">
          <option value="buddy">Buddy</option>
          <option value="cute">Cute</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5" id="mp3play">
      </div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var music = $('#selectedmusic option:selected').text();
    $("#mp3play").html(music);   
  });
```

Comment: You assign it once the body is started but never let it listen on a change

Comment: @OliverF. How to let it listen on a change? I'm new to web programming.... can you explain it detailed? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectedmusic').change(function(){
        $("#mp3play").text(this.value);
    });
});
```

You have to tell the javascript to watch the change of the value of this select-box. Else it would just watch it once when the body is ready but never update when you change it, because you don't say that it should.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#selectedmusic').change(function){
    var music = $('#selectedmusic option:selected').text();
    $("#mp3play").html(music);   
  });
});
```